# Core data is creating empty entry while updating and existing record

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

**Problem :** Core data is creating empty entry, and I've seen all possible resources before posting here.

**Short Explaination:**
I have a cart in which I'm checking if the product already exists, if it does, I'm updating the count by 1. If it doesn't exist, I'm adding it to core data and showing in my collection view.

**Current Situation with example:**

The value is updating but everytime another empty value is also added.
Suppose I click on add to cart, then it is added to cart, again when I click the count is updated, but along with that another empty entry is added. So if I press the add to cart button 5 times, the count of main object becomes 5, but another 4 empty entries are also added.

**Image:**

[image: Image showing empty cells and count of object updated]

**code for adding to Core Data**

```
@IBAction func addToCartAction(_ sender: Any){

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let cartEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Cart", in: managedContext)!

        let imageViewModel =  self.product?.images.items.first
        let urlString: String = (imageViewModel?.url.absoluteString)!

        let varientModel =  self.product?.variants.items.first
        let cart = NSManagedObject(entity: cartEntity, insertInto: managedContext)

        if self.checkIfAlreadyInCart(handle: self.productHandle!)
        {
            let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Cart")

            request.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "productHandle = %@ AND variantName = %@", argumentArray: [self.productHandle!,self.selectedVariant!])
            do {
                let result = try managedContext.fetch(request) as? [Cart]

                var currentValue = result![0].value(forKey: "productQty") as! Int
                currentValue += 1
                result![0].setValue(currentValue, forKey: "productQty")

                    try managedContext.save()
                }
                    catch let error as NSError {
                        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    }
        }

        else{

        cart.setValue(1, forKey: "productQty")
        cart.setValue( self.product?.title, forKeyPath: "productName")
        cart.setValue( self.product?.price, forKey: "productPrice")
        cart.setValue( self.product?.price, forKey: "productComparePrice")
        cart.setValue(urlString, forKey: "productImageUrl")
        cart.setValue(self.productHandle, forKey: "productHandle")
        cart.setValue(varientModel?.id, forKey: "productVariantID")
        cart.setValue(varientModel?.title, forKey: "variantName")

            do {
                try managedContext.save()
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

**and the `self.checkIfAlreadyInCart(handle: self.productHandle!)` function is :**

```
func checkIfAlreadyInCart(handle: String) -> Bool{

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        do {
            let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Cart")

            request.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "productHandle = %@ AND variantName = %@", argumentArray: [self.productHandle!,self.selectedVariant!])

            let result = try context.fetch(request)
            if result.count > 0 {
                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Some exception occured.")
            return false
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions or solutions are welcome. If you can suggest some good places to learn about core data it would be great as I have very less knowledge about it.

Comment: At `let cart = NSManagedObject(entity, ...)` you create a new object, *before* checking if it already exists.

Comment: @MartinR any suggested solution?

Comment: @MartinR , worked! Thanks for the hint, any suggested sources to read from?